# Terraform mixed VCS + API driven runs, applying non-default-branch configuration versions

Tags: terraform, terraform-enterprise

I am using a terraform enterprise instance to manage three workspaces that represent infrastructure for the various environments of an application (development, pre-prod and prod have isolated infrastructure). The workspaces themselves are configured using a `tfe_workspace` resource.

I'm using a VCS-driven flow to create the configuration versions as I need speculative plan runs on PRs and I'm fine with automatic runs being created for master. I'm using the API to determine when to apply runs so that the staging environment can be applied and have automated tests run against it before the production workspace run is applied.

This works fairly well, except that I have been unable to use the api to apply non-default-branch configuration versions (i.e. from a PR) to the development workspace. Any run I create using a configuration version that was not created from the master branch does creates a `plan-only` run.

Is there a way via the Terraform Enterprise API to apply a PR configuration version?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by not reusing the PR's configuration version, and creating one of my own via the API instead.